# Getting Emacs to recognise custom math delimiters so it can colour the face accordingly

Tags: emacs, latex, elisp, auctex, emacs-faces

I have found a code to make typing equations in LaTeX in a simpler and faster way. Instead of typing

```
\begin{equation}
\end{equation}
```

I can now type

```
\be
\ee
```

It works great and I am happy with it. The code, found in [this](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) document (p. 13), is

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\be}{\begingroup
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{2pt}
\eqnarray%
\@ifstar{\nonumber}{}%
}
\newcommand{\ee}{\endeqnarray\endgroup}
\makeatother
```

My problem is that I use emacs, and it doesn't recognise those math delimiters and hence it doesn't give the face the proper math colour. I have tried to customise this by using the command `M-x customize-apropos` to try and find something I could use, but the closest I got were the variables

1. `'font-latex-math-environments'`,
   which I don't think is what I am
   after since from what I can see I
   can only type the name of the
   command which goes inside the curly
   brackets in `\begin{}` and `\end{}`
2. `'font-latex-make-built-in-keywords'`,
   which would require more knowledge
   from me than I have, and I don't
   even know whether it would work.

What I would like to know, thus, is how to set up Emacs so that whenever I used the pair `\be` and `\ee` it would give the face the same colour as I set up for math. I imagine this would require an emacs lisp code, which would be great so I could modify it to include other things if so I wished.

Can anyone help me getting this done?

Comment: General FYI: [Avoid eqnarray!](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align) [Avoid eqnarray!](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/) [Avoid eqnarray!](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/maths/eqnarray-align-environment/) [Avoid eqnarray!](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~hildebr/tex/displays.html) Use [align or equation or something else from amsmath instead](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1166/which-command-should-i-use-for-displayed-equations-really).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I actually use align normally, but that is irrelevant for the question...

Answer (score 7):

This is not really an answer to your question, but if it's just about saving keystrokes for writing an `equation` environment, you might want to try the following.

From the tags under your question, I assume you're using [AUCTeX mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/). With that, instead of typing

```
\begin{equation}

\end{equation}
```

every time, use the following shortcut to have AUCTeX insert an environment interactively: <kbd>C-c C-e</kbd>. This will prompt your for the name of the environment ("equation") which you can type using tab-completion.

So you do save a couple of keystrokes, the result is syntactically correct, you don't need the additional `\be` and `\ee` commands, and what's best is that this approach is generic, i.e., it works for *all* LaTeX environments, not just `equation`.

Comment: Also, if `equation` is what you used most recently, then hitting `C-c C-e` gives `equation` as the default prompt, so you just have to hit Enter.

Comment: I knew that, though I will confess I don't use it and it sort of solves some of my problems. The thing is, I would like to know how I can get Emacs to colour some of my custom made commands, and I thought that if I found a solution to the question above, I would be able to figure out how to do the other things I want to by understanding the code and then changing it slightly to fit my other needs.